# ancient sort of designs and window types

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to find references to certain types of objects, but, I don't know what particularly they are called, What do you call [This particular type of architecture? and is there any name for the sort of curvy designs?](https://www.reddit.com/r/FinalFantasy/comments/7y1hln/ff7_sector_5_slums_church_inspiration_xpost_from/)

[image: church]

And what do you call [this particular style of windows, this kind I usually recon seeing in castles of vampires in movies](http://forums.cgsociety.org/t/ancient-hall-advent-children-fight-sequence/994681)?

[image: hall]

Comment: It would help if you published an actual pic, instead of making us go search...but it is called Gothic

Comment: ... but not all [vaulted windows](https://wallsheaven.com/wall-murals/elements-of-the-architecture-of-the-old-building.-vaulted-windows.-close-up-A117695462) are gothic. They aren't only found in vampire movies.

Comment: Also see "clearstory" windows, not all of which are gothic.

Comment: @Cascabel, I don't know if I can do that due to the copyrights of the images

Comment: It is always best to give attributions and if possible a link to the .jpeg or whatever. Then there should be no problem. Beyond that...sometimes you gotta look at the meta-data to see if the the publisher has not "stolen" it from the original foto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual source for the first image is [here](https://romanrobroek.nl/portfolio/former-chapel/), which explains that it's a [19th-century copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_Revival_architecture) of the [Gothic style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_architecture).

Google's reverse image search shows the second is concept art for Halo 3. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with vampires, who tend to get either Gothic or Romanian. It reminds me of [Ottoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_architecture), [Persian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_architecture), or [Mughal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mughal_architecture), with their onionate tops, albeit nothing on Wikipedia looks quite right.

Comment: "19th-century copy of the Gothic style" or more simply, "neo-Gothic," or "Gothic Revival."  I had the same thought about the second image and thought to propose "Moresque" - though those windows are typically not filled with stained glass.  Perhaps it's a later addition to an originally Moresque design (or perhaps the video game designers just didn't know/care what they were doing).

Comment: Yeah, it's a video game design. It's not a traditional style from anywhere. Just what "looks cool".

Comment: @lly, This sort of window was also used for FFVII: Advent Children, The window has sort of random looking glass with more magenta pieces, ottoman, persian look a bit different

Answer (score 2):

The first is ["gothic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_architecture).

I don't know a name for the windows in the second: they look a bit [art nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Nouveau) to me.